# Simple tutorial for Neo4J and using it with django + python

Tags: python, django, neo4j

Is there any simple tutorial for learning Neo4J. I went through its official manual and found very confusing for me since i am from mysql background. I just wanted to learn Neo4J but i am really finding a hard time. Also there is not much books available for Neo4J

Please help me with this

Comment: Are you interested in material related to Neo4j itself, the REST API, or Django-specific integration, or general graph best practices?

Answer (score 11):

I just updated [neo4django's documentation](http://neo4django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), and like to think it reads like a tutorial. I'd appreciate feedback!

Comment: not supports latest version of django, installing it installs django 1.4 version as of now :(

Comment: Please check this out - https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/django-neomodel.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the Bulbs Quickstart tutorial (http://bulbflow.com/quickstart/). Bulbs works with any Python Web framework, including Django, Flask, and Pyramid.

Comment: thanks for the info on bulbflow. I never knew there is something like that.

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice integration for Neo4j+Django: https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django
and I notice a tutorial on github: https://github.com/johanlundberg/neo4j-django-tutorial

There are a few books in the works, covering general concepts about working with a graph database and Neo4j specifics. But they haven't yet hit the shelves.

For now, the Neo4j manual is the best material available for learning.

-Andreas

Answer (score 3):

neo4django is super outdated. Check the updated options at:

https://neo4j.com/developer/python/

About the tutorial you can find many free resources at the website. You can also start with Cypher, the query language:

https://neo4j.com/developer/cypher/

Answer (score 0):

FYI: neomodel is also beginning to be outdated. It's not compatible with the latest neo-driver version for instance.

It lacks updates, and apart from that, we had some serious threading issues with it - seems like it is not thread safe/not synchronous, or not doing the whole async/sync thing correctly. (since Neo4J is async, and Django is not (yet))

The idea behind these libs was to have some kind of abstraction layer, like an ORM, but what's the point if it is not any more convenient than Cypher, nor can it do everything Cypher can, so you start writing queries in Cypher anyhow. Having something graph database agnostic is also fake, since it only serves Neo4J.

We already rewrote all queries in Cypher, now I just have to find a way to do the data modelling natively.